# Can I use BLE scan in an android app to scan for a normal bluetooth device and get RSSI values and timestamp for distance calculation?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have seen a couple of answers on StackOverflow itself and most of them said no but had different use cases. I am trying to build an Android app which would be able to return an approximate distance of various devices which are in its range. I am currently using the `android.bluetooth.le` package for the same but I wanted to know whether it will return a result if the other device is transmitting a normal Bluetooth signal and not a BLE signal. If not, is there a way to get around this to building an app which would be able to get RSSI values for both BLE and Bluetooth devices?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by _normal Bluetooth signal and not a BLE signal_ ? Are your referring to BLE and Bluetooth Classic?

Comment: Yes I am referring to BLE and Classic Bluetooth